# How to find net income/loss of a company based on equity along with owner's investment/withdrawals?

Tags: accounting, equity

We know that net income/loss is found by this equation:

> **Net income/loss = Revenues - Expenses**

But what if both revenue and expense statements are unknown? I have the following information of the company:

---

**December 31, 2008**

Assets: $55,000
Liabilities: $26,000
Equity: $29,000

**December 31, 2009**

Assets: $58,000
Liabilities: $35,000
Equity: $23,000

**During the year 2009**
Owner's Investments: $12,000
Owner's Withdrawals: $10,000

---

How do I find out the net income/loss based on the provided information?

Comment: equity dropped 5k while the owner injected net capital of 2k so it lost 7k.

Comment: @doug how did you come at 7k? Sorry but I'm a newbie in accounting. I'd really appreciate step-by step instructions if you can provide

Comment: @Steve This is a homework question, so presumably the answers + guide is in the back of your textbook / ask your teacher.

Comment: Questions about accounting are off-topic unless they relate directly to personal finance or investing from an individual's perspective.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon if I could've just done that, I wouldn't have asked here, would I?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea sorry, I didn't know where I could ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Net income can also be measured as the change in equity.

> Net income/loss = Ending equity - Starting equity

In your case the equity has also been changed by the owner investing and withdrawing money from the company, so we need to adjust for that:

> Net income/loss = Ending equity - Starting equity + owner withdrawals - owner investments

Net income/loss = 23000 + 10000 - 29000 - 12000 = -8000

The company had a net loss of $8000.